# Export a specific page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, export

How can I export a specific page in Wordpress?

I want to use a page from one wordpress instance in another wordpress instance, both having same theme.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you just need to export one post, why not just copy/paste it over to the other installation? Are you looking to have the two pages mirror each other when updates are made?

Comment: No I can't just copy paste the page because it is having lot of different data like corousels, images, sliders etc

Comment: Personally, if it were me, 1 post is not something i'd over complicate by trying to export the post and then import, even with the dependencies like sliders and carousels. If it has images, upload those to your other WordPress installation's media library. Make sure the dependencies for the sliders, and carousels are included in your other WordPress installation's theme, which should already be the case if it's the same theme. Then copy over all of the fields from your post, and update the images that have broken links to the images in  your other WordPress installation's media library.

Answer (score 47):

1. Go to your admin panel then go to Users > Add New.
2. Create a new user with username `Exporter` and set the role to Author and save.
3. Change the author of the post or posts that you need to export by selecting them and then clicking edit. Change the author to `Exporter`

   [image]
4. Go to Tools > Export and choose what type of content you want to export and select the author `Exporter` then click Download Export File. The resulting file contains all the information you need in XML format.

   [image]
5. Go to the WordPress website where you want to import this information and go to Tools > Import > WordPress.

Comment: The problem with this approach is you now you have to remember which author wrote which blog post/page and convert them back to the original author afterwards.

Comment: Exporter author name is just for example. you can get all posts belonged to any author, and then import them. Or you can set author name whatever you want to. you do not need to remember author name.

Comment: This works. It's not pretty… but it works. One upside is if that user only exists on the export site, and not the import site, then Wordpress will automatically ask you to assign it to a user on import 

Comment: In my case the resulting new page was total garbage. It mixed multiple themes and lost all formatting. I succeeded with plugin NS Cloner

Comment: This is such a hack, but also the sort of hack I'd be proud of.

Comment: This one's very clever!

Comment: Worked perfect. I also used the plugin "Export media with selected content" combined.
Link: https://wordpress.org/plugins/export-media-with-selected-content/

Answer (score 0):

In case someone still stumbles upon this question: I found [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/single-post-exporter/) plugin, which works like a charm for me. Just watch out for images and other content that might not be exported with the xml file. After you export the page you can go to Tools > Import Data and import the xml file.

Comment: Sadly this plugin is now closed as of Sept '21 because of a security concern :(

Answer (score 0):

Similar to *Ali Raza*'s answer, if you don't want to create an author to export just one page you can

- modify the publish date of the page to a date before the creation of the installation
- and while exporting select that date and export
- then change the date back

`(would've commented but not enough rep)`

Answer (score -2):

If you want to copy pages or sites in between a multisite installation, try the plugin NS Cloner in free version:

1. Install plugin "NS Cloner"
2. My Sites -> Network Admin -> Sites and put mouse over your sit
3. Clone

   → an full copy of a site with all pages is made - in my case it was perfect identical

Comment: The OP wanted to export/import ONE particular post. Not to clone everything.

Answer (score -4):

There are many ways to do this.

1. Download wp-coder plugin
2. Go to page which you wanna clone
3. Inspect Element and copy all html code and paste it in notepad. Also copy all code from style.css and paste it in notepad.
4. Now navigate to wp coder and copy paste html css where you wanna make same page

Note: install wp-coder where you wanna add same page